# use Google analytics to track visits from application

Tags: google-analytics

is it possible use Google analytics to track visits from  nonbrowser application?  will ga be able to recognize custom user agents or other http headers?  Anyone has experience in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at [Google's Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/index.html), which includes a section you can expand titled "Specialized Tracking"? You will find explanations of how to track gadgets, mobile apps, and Flash apps.